# Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.android.provider

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fileprovider

My application keeps crashing and I get this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.android.provider`

This is the code that's causing the error. Specifically, the `photoURI` line:

```
photoFile?.also {
    photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        Objects.requireNonNull(applicationContext),
        "com.example.android.provider",
        it
    )
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1)
}
```

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` I have this:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

In my `provider_paths.xml` file I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong? I don't understand what's causing the error cause everything seems to be right.

Comment: The authority `String` you're passing in `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` doesn't match the `android:authorities` value on the `<provider>` element. Have a look at the top-voted answer on the linked duplicate to see what to pass there.